# how do i expose function from anonymous self invoking function?

Tags: javascript, function

```
 (function(){
   var a = function () {
     alert("hey now!! ");
   };
   return {"hi":function(){return a;}};
 })();

 hi();
```

This code doesn' t work. How do i expose a function??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The self invoking function returns an object with the property `hi`, this object is not added to the global scope so that you can use the property directly. Put the result of the function in a variable:

```
var o =
(function(){

  var a = function (){
    alert("hey now!! ");
  };

  return {"hi":function(){return a;}};

})();
```

Using the property to call the function will only return the function contained in the variable `a`, so you have to call the return value from the function to call the function that contains the alert:

```
o.hi()();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/9twaH/

Answer (score 6):

There are two basic ways:

```
var MyNameSpace = (function(){

     function a (){
       alert("hey now!! ");
     };

     return {a: a};

})();

MyNameSpace.a();
```

or

```
(function(){

     function a (){
       alert("hey now!! ");
     };

     MyNameSpace = {a: a};

})();

MyNameSpace.a();
```

I prefer the 2nd way since it seems cleaner

It is called the "revealing module pattern" btw, which you can read up on to understand it better :)

https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

Comment: Note that the second way creates a global variable, while the first way creates a variable in whatever the surrounding scope is (might be global, might not).

Comment: That is true. The example was a bit limited. Normally I create a global variable as a toplevel namespace and build on that to minimize DOM pollution

Comment: Does jQuery use the second one to expose their `$` method to the global scope, because when I look at the source code it doesn't look like the first?

Comment: Your link is now dead and leads to malware.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var obj = (function(){

 var a=  function (){
    alert("hey now!! ");
 };

 return {"hi":function(){return a;}};

 })();

 obj.hi()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the return value of the anonymous function to a variable in the current scope:

```
var f = (function() {
    var a = function() {
        alert("hey now!! ");
    };
    return {
        "hi": function() { return a; }
    };
})();
f.hi()();
```

Answer (score 0):

It?

```
(function(){
   var a = function () {
     alert("hey now!! ");
   };
   return {"hi":function(){return a;}};
 })().hi()();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in order to expose the function, instead of its code, the syntax should be

```
var obj2 = (function(){

     var a=  function (){
        alert("hey now!! ");
     };

 return {"hi":a};

 })();

alert(obj2.hi());
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could wrap your 'hi' function in an IIFE like so...

```
var myFunction = (function(){
   var a = function () {
     alert("hey now!! ");
   };
   return {
       "hi": (function(){
           return a;
       }())
   };

 })();

 myFunction.hi();
```