# How do I expose data from within ES6 blocks?

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6, export

ES6 has introduced block scopes using `let` and `const`. What's the correct way to `export` data from within the block scope, so that I can access it from outside. [Using IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513645/how-do-i-expose-function-from-anonymous-self-invoking-function) you could just assign a the expression to a variable.

```
{
   const add = (a, b) => a+b
   // export add?
}
```

Using `export` within the block throws an error.

`'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`

One way I've found is to assign it to the global `window` object

```
{
   const add = (a, b) => a+b
   window.add = add
}
```

I'm just curious to know what the suggested way to do this is?

Comment: What's the purpose of the block here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function, and return the value you need.

```js
const Add = () => {
    return 'function add returned...';
};
```

Comment: Can you give a small example. That would be helpful

Comment: Something like this:

const Add = () => {
    return 'function add returned...';
};

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a variable outside of the block and just assign it a value inside the block.

```
let myVar;

const myFunc = () => {
    myVar = 'foo';
};
```